# Mark entries in df which have an overlap in time ranges

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a df the following df_test

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 10, 20], [1, 5, 8], [1, 5, 15], [1, 13, 14], [1, 18, 21],[2, 2, 2], [1, 21, 100], [1, 1, 50]]),
                   columns=['id', 'charging_start_in_ms', 'charging_stop_in_ms'])
df_test['valid'] = True

print(f"{df_test} \n")
>>> id  charging_start_in_ms    charging_stop_in_ms valid
  0 1   10                      20                  True
  1 1   5                       8                   True
  2 1   5                       15                  True
  3 1   13                      14                  True
  4 1   18                      21                  True
  5 2   2                       2                   True
  6 1   21                      100                 True
  7 1   1                       50                  True
```

I am looking for an efficient way, to mark invalid enries, which have

1. same id
2. overlap in time

I came this far:

```
col2 = 'id'
col3 = 'charging_start_in_ms'
col4 = 'charging_stop_in_ms'

for index, row in df_test.iterrows():
    id = df_test.at[index, col2]
    start = df_test.at[index, col3]
    stop = df_test.at[index, col4]

    #sort out transaction with different id
    df_temp = df_test[df_test[col2] == id]
    #sort out transactions before
    df_temp = df_temp[~((df_temp[col3] < start) & (df_temp[col4] < start))]
    #sort out transactions after
    df_temp = df_temp[~((df_temp[col3] > stop) & (df_temp[col4] > stop))] 

    #print(f"Index: {index}")
    #print(df_temp)

    for index in df_temp.index:
        df_test.loc[index, 'valid'] = False
            
df_test
>>> id  charging_start_in_ms    charging_stop_in_ms valid
  0 1   10                      20                  False
  1 1   5                       8                   False
  2 1   5                       15                  False
  3 1   13                      14                  False
  4 1   18                      21                  False
  5 2   2                       2                   False
  6 1   21                      100                 False
  7 1   1                       50                  False
```

My problem is, I am always selecting the observed item as well, so finally all items are set to valid=False, but I want item id=2 to be valid=True. How can I manage this, with keeping the option, that propably a different item can have the same id and exact charging_start_in_ms and/or charging_stop_in_ms.

Any hints? Thanks

EDIT: I added this to drop the index

```
#sort out same index
df_temp = df_test.drop([index])
```

EDIT II: Another working solution would be:

```
    #3 cases for overlapping charging time
    #case 1: index.start <= stop <= index.stop
    #case 2: index.start <= start <= index.stop
    #case 3: start <= index start and stop >= index.stop
    df_temp = df.query(f"{col2} == '{id}' and (({start} <= {col4} <= {stop}) or ({start} <= {col3} <= {stop}) or ({col3} <= {start} and {col4} >= {stop}))")
    #sort out same index
    df_temp = df_temp.drop([index])
```

I guess it works, but the next problem is, that it needs around 6s for 0.01% of my overall data. So if I interpolate, it will need around 100min (for 326000 entries). Is there any faster solution?

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution would be skipping the target index on your inner for loop like

```
for ii in df_temp.index:
    if ii == index:
        continue
df_test.loc[index, 'valid'] = False
```

it would produce this output

```
>>> df_test
   id  charging_start_in_ms  charging_stop_in_ms  valid
0   1                    10                   20  False
1   1                     5                    8  False
2   1                     5                   15  False
3   1                    13                   14  False
4   1                    18                   21  False
5   2                     2                    2   True
6   1                    21                  100  False
7   1                     1                   50  False
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found out, I could just drop the index as well in my chain of selecting (df_temp = df_test.drop([index]) #sort out same index). I'll play some more to find a satisfying answer.